# How to remove Dynamic UITextField from Subview

Tags: ios, iphone, subview

How to remove the array of `UITextField` from Scroll Subview, initially when I call API I get some Array Value based on Count I have created Dynamic `UITextFiled` in My View, But I do know how to remove the Subview

**here my sample Code:**

```
// NSArray *strings;
// UIScrollView *scrollView;
// NSMutableArray *textFields;

self.textFields = [NSMutableArray array];

const CGFloat width = 320;
const CGFloat height = 31;
const CGFloat margin = 0;
CGFloat y = 0;

for(NSString *string in strings) {
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] 
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, width, height)];
textField.delegate = self;
textField.text = string;

[scrollView addSubview:textField];
[textFields addObject:textField];
[textField release];

y += height + margin;
}

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, y - margin);
```

Comment: You want to remove all the textFields ?

Comment: Use tags for each text fields(use the array index as a tag simply). So you can remove whatever text field you need to remove.

Comment: You want to remove only those textField thats you are adding using this method ?

Comment: yessss bro @NiravD

Comment: @batMan007 Mate you haven't respond have you made it or still need help with this one ?

Comment: @NiravD still i didnt fixed that issue bro dono where to remove Subviews properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firs of all when you are creating this dynamic `textField` set single `tag` like `101`.

```
for(NSString *string in strings) {
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, width, height)];
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.text = string;
    //Set tag 101
    textField.tag = 101;
    [scrollView addSubview:textField];
    [textFields addObject:textField];
    [textField release];

    y += height + margin;
}
```

Now make one method to remove all this dynamic textFields.

```
- (void)removeAllDynamicTextFields {

    for(UIView *view in scrollView.subViews){
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && view.tag == 101){
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @batMan007 Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove that textfield from your view then you can simply removi that textfield from your superview.

```
[yourtextfield removeFromSuperView];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollView.subViews.forEach({textField in
            if textField is UITextField , textField.tag == XX {
                textField.removeFromSuperView()
            }
        })
```

Comment: This is Swift not Objective C

Answer (score -1):

Add tag and then remove whatever text view with loop

```
for (UITextView *i in scrollView){
    if([i isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]){
        UITextView *tv = (UITextView *)i;
        if(tv.tag == 1){ // Whatever textview want to remove add tag here
            /// Write your code
            [tv removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```